# Half completed codes for arraylist

Tags: java

I am having my final exam tomorrow so i am practicing some questions.But i am stuck at this question.I am given a person class file and a half completed quiz10 file whereby i have to fill up.The quiz10 codes are halfway done(given).

I need to implement a function `findPersonWhoseNameStartWith` which returns the names of the persons in the list who start with A. But i have no idea how.

Output wanted:

result:April,Adam

```
public class Person{
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(String name,int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "" + name;
    }
}
```

Half given codes(I have indicate which part i have attempted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quiz10{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Person>list=new ArrayList<Person>();
    list.add(new Person("April",9));
    list.add(new Person("Adam",3));
    list.add(new Person("bil",9));
    list.add(new Person("cpril",9));
    list.add(new Person("dpril",9));

    ArrayList<Person>result=findPersonWhoseNameStartWith(list,"A");
    System.out.println("result:");


//START DOING FROM HERE

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        Person p=list.get(i);

        if(p.findPersonWhoseNameStartWith("A");
    }

}
```

Comment: what have you tried? `I'm stuck` is not valid. You need to specify exactly what is causing you trouble.

Comment: Sorry but this question makes no sense.

Comment: I have used for loops.I have indicated in the quiz 10 codes.Yes,this question seems so strange.I am supposed to get person whose name start with "A" using quiz10.But somehow,i think my prof set a strange question.

Comment: Your toString method : need not concatenate.  name is string. You can return as it is

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that.I only need to add on to my quiz10 codes.I have tried out on my own.can anyone give me guidance how to proceed?

Comment: String has a "startsWith(prefix)" method which should help you.

Comment: Person.getName() returns a string. Please check APIs on String, you will find some interesting methods for you

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. you are right you have to iterate over the list. Now for each entry output it if it starts with `'A'`. It's very simple and a single if statement way easier than what you imagine it seems.

Comment: i was thinking if(p.findPeopleWhoseNameStartsWith("A").equal("A")

Comment: Does it make sense?Because i want to compare and see if they match

Comment: It is alright.I failed once before and i know i am repeating this module again.But i rather fail now and make sure i get my concepts right again(:

Comment: @Drogba please avoid putting offensive comments here. Our goal is to help, not to demotivate or offend somebody.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev OK. I have deleted it.

Comment: @user2179615 actually as I mentioned you are over complicating it. You don't need to perform a find within the cycle. Simply check if the entry starts with 'A'.

Comment: I think i get what you mean.Shall go try out on my own and update my answer again(:

Answer (score 0):

```
// pass your personList and the prefix, return a list of person starting with the prefix you specified
private List<Person> findPersonWhoseNameStartWith(List<Person> personList, String prefix) {
      // create a list to store your result
      List<Person> matchedList = new ArrayList<Person>();

      // TODO iterate personList
      // add them to the matchedList if the prefix matches

      return matchedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Person> findAPersonWhoStartsWith(List<Person> persons, String aLetter){
    List<String> personsNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(persons!=null && aLetter!=null && !aLetter.isEmpty()){
        for(Person aPerson:persons){
            if(aPerson.getName().startsWith(aLetter)){
                personsNames.add(aPerson);
            }
        }
    }
    return personsNames;
}
```

Comment: Note that the for loop used here is a short hand method that is a little different than the for(int i; i<LEN; i++) than is typically used in school.  I will typically only use the for-loop with an iterator if I need to know the index for some reason.  Here it doesnt appear that you need to know that.